# Error ::: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '28,37'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression

I tried to fit a logistic regression on my data but i got this error
**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '28,37'**
My code:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                            stratify=y, 
                                            test_size=0.3)
 logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
 logisticRegr.fit(X_train, y_train)
 predictions = logisticRegr.predict(X_test)
```

How can i solve it please.?

Comment: It seems you have a wrong decimal delimiter in your X_train a comma instead of a dot

Comment: replace "," per "." Another tip, if bigger number contains dot like (1.234,84) you will get problems too

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong separator in the string. You should use a `.` instead of a `,`.

Compare:

```
print(float('28,37'))
```

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '28,37'

To:

```
print(float('28.37'))
```

> 28.37

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
df.column1=df.column1.str.replace(',', '.', regex=False)
df.column1 = df.column1.astype(float)
```

After I tested

```
  column0      column1
0    row0     179319,0
1    row1      89659,5
2    row2      59773.0
3    row3     44829,75
4    row4      35863.8
5    row5      29886.5
6    row6      25617,0
7    row7    22414.875
8    row8  19924.33333
  column0      column1
0    row0     179319.0
1    row1      89659.5
2    row2      59773.0
3    row3     44829.75
4    row4      35863.8
5    row5      29886.5
6    row6      25617.0
7    row7    22414.875
8    row8  19924.33333
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ',' inside of string because you cannot convert string like "28,37" to float. So the string should like "28.37"

```
print(float("28.37"))
```

> 28.37

Comment: thank you i solve it . but i have some variables with date that cause error like this **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '05OCT2013'** have you an idea how to do ? (in logistic reg)